# VBA Error 1004 Object Range failed for _Global

Tags: vba, excel

I need to make a little VBA Application for a School project.

I recorded a Macro which Resize all Cells and then make them green. After that I select specific Cells and recolor them in white. So the result should be the Excel logo. However when I run the code there is an Error 1004 Range Object failed for _Global.

Code:

```
Sub Resize()

Columns("A:BZ").ColumnWidth = 2.71
Rows("1:1000").RowHeight = 15
Cells.Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 4485149
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With

Union(Range( _
    "O14:P15,L7:T7,S5:T6,P6:Q6,E38:F47,G46:J47,G42:J43,G38:J39,N38:O39,O40:R41,R38:S39,P42:Q43,O44:R45,N46:O47,R46:S47,W38:X47,Y46:AB47,Y38:AB39,AF38:AK39,AF40:AG47,AH46:AK47,AH42:AK43,AO38:AP47,AQ46:AT47,R6,Y7:AP9,AN10:AP31,Y29:AM31,AF10:AF28,AG24:AM24,Y24:AE24" _
    ), Range( _
    "AG19:AM19,AG14:AM14,Y14:AE14,V4:X33,U5:U32,T12:T25,S14:S23,R16:R21,Q18:Q19,Q28:T32,M26:R27,N24:Q25,O22:P23,L28:P31,H28:K30,F9:G29,H8:J27,K12:K25,L14:L23,M16:M21,N18:N19,K8:T9,M10:R11,N12:Q13" _
    )).Select
Cells.Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You can step through your code line by line in the vbexplorer by pressing F8 can you try that?

Comment: what line is throwing the error?

Comment: In which line is happening the error? We probably cannot "send you a complete solution" but we can help you to reach your solution.

Comment: Check your Ranges inside your `Union` line. Try defining a `Dim UnionRng        As Range` then set it to `Set UnionRng = Union(Range("O14:P15,L7:T7,S5:T6"), Range("P6:Q6,E38:F47,G46:J47"))` you'll see it's just fine. So it's something inside your Ranges, maybe they are overlapping or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the string fed to `Range` must be less then 256 characters, while your first range has just 257... so just shift some characters to the 2nd range

furthermore you're selecting all cells instead of wanted ones

see code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Resize()

    With Range("A1:BZ1000")
        .ColumnWidth = 2.71
        .RowHeight = 15
        With .Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 4485149
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End With

    With Union(Range( _
        "O14:P15,L7:T7,S5:T6,P6:Q6,E38:F47,G46:J47,G42:J43,G38:J39,N38:O39,O40:R41,R38:S39,P42:Q43,O44:R45,N46:O47,R46:S47,W38:X47,Y46:AB47,Y38:AB39,AF38:AK39,AF40:AG47,AH46:AK47,AH42:AK43,AO38:AP47,AQ46:AT47,R6,Y7:AP9,AN10:AP31,Y29:AM31" _
        ), Range( _
        "AF10:AF28,AG24:AM24,Y24:AE24,AG19:AM19,AG14:AM14,Y14:AE14,V4:X33,U5:U32,T12:T25,S14:S23,R16:R21,Q18:Q19,Q28:T32,M26:R27,N24:Q25,O22:P23,L28:P31,H28:K30,F9:G29,H8:J27,K12:K25,L14:L23,M16:M21,N18:N19,K8:T9,M10:R11,N12:Q13" _
        )).Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: BTW you could limit "A1:BZ1000" to "A1:BZ50" and still have the wanted "Excel" logo appear properly

Comment: Exactly that was the problem, thank you! @user3598756 In need this space for other stuff but thanks for the advise ;)

Comment: You are welcome. Since you're learning VBA, as you've seen here you should always use fully qualified `Range` references instead of `Select`/`Selection`/`Activate`/`ActiveXXX` pattern, which is to be _confined_ to veeeery few special cases